# Always returning null value from MS Access database vb.net

Tags: sql, .net, database, vb.net

I'm trying to execute this query in vb.net windows form application

```
select SUM(Amount) 
from FeesRecord 
where Student_Id=@p1 
AND Batch_Id=(select Batch_Id from Admissions where Admission_Id=@p2)
AND ReExam_Id IS NULL)
```

I set correct values in parameters but i'm always getting empty result in executescaler.

My code

```
cmd.CommandText = "select SUM(Amount) from FeesRecord where (Student_Id=@p1 AND Batch_Id=(select Batch_Id from Admissions where Admission_Id=@p2) AND ReExam_Id IS NULL)"
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtregno.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", gv1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
                        MsgBox(cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString)
```

Comment: Could you provide the parameter values you use, and what data the tables contain related to those values?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you opened the connection saying `con.Open()` and referenced that connecting string in your command object `cmd.Connection = con`.

Second, you can modify your query to be like below using simple join

```
select SUM(fr.Amount) 
from FeesRecord fr join Admissions a
on fr.Batch_Id = a.Batch_Id
where fr.Student_Id = @p1 
AND a.Admission_Id = @p2
AND fr.ReExam_Id IS NULL;
```

If you are still getting null return then run the same query in DB directly and see what result you get. most probably, the `WHERE` condition doesn't matches any record.

Comment: I used this query but i'm getting error " Error in From Clause"